# ecs-deploy has not completed (timeout)

Tags: amazon-ecs, circleci

guys.
I faced to confusing problem.

I use aws(ecr / ecs), and circle ci to deploy.
and using [ecs-deploy](https://github.com/silinternational/ecs-deploy) command.

circle ci deployment has timeouted.
but, deployment has been successful until last week(Friday).

we changed any modules kotlin class and anything after last successful deployment.
then, our deployment had get timeouted.

— what I did —
06/10/2021  module changed and deploy successful
06/17/2021   module changed and deploy failure
————

what happen is this?
is anyone experienced similer problem?

our changes is production module; then I can’t show you it.
Sorry we can't show you any evidence; if you need more infomation, I'll give you as possible.

I think our changes cause this problem;
but it is small changes.

I have no idea to solve this problem.
if you had got similer situation, please tell me what solution it.

Thanks.